# "warning, rule cannot be matched" Defining String in lex

Tags: lex

I was trying to create a rule to create a String and print it.
So heres the code:

```
 %{
char buff[200];
char *s;
}%
%X STRLIT
%%
\"                  {BEGIN STRLIT; s = buf;}
<STRLIT><<EOF>>     {printf("unterminated string literal\n");
                     BEGIN 0;}
<STRLIT>\\          {*s++ = '\\';}
<STRLIT>\f          {*s++ = '\f';}
<STRLIT>\n          ;
<STRLIT>\r          ;
<STRLIT>\t          {*s++ = '\t';}
<STRLIT>.           {*s++ = *yytext;}
<STRLIT>\"          {*s = 0;printf("STRING(%s)\n",buf);BEGIN 0;}
```

The error is in the last line, but i cant figure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there are multiple rules that can match on the current input and produce a match of the same size, `flex` will take the rule that's defined first.

So, for example, if there's a `\t`, both the rules `\t` and `.` could match, but `\t` comes first, so it's the one that's used. But if a `"` appears, `.` is used because `\"` comes after it in your flex file. So there's no way that the `\"` rule in `STRLIT` would ever be used and that's what the error is about.

To fix this, simply move `.` to be the last rule. That way it will only match if none of the other rules match.